# Reorder DIVs on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

### We are looking for a solution, to reorder DIVs, if the screen size gets smaller.

Our divs images are grey and white.

On a screen size that is bigger than 1024px we use a 3 column layout.
If the screen size gets smaller we use a 2 column layout.
The problem is that we have to reorder the divs on the 2 column layout.
Otherwise the layout breaks and we don't have the chess pattern.

**Take a look where that should take place: [printnil.com](http://printnil.com/collections/all)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px)  {
      .mix {width: 100%;}
}
 @media only screen and (min-width:568px) {
     .mix {width: 50%;}
}  

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
   .mix {width: 33.333%;}
 }


<div class="mix grey">

<a href="/products/angebotsmappe">

<img src="{{ 'grey.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Urkundenmappe - DIN 4,95 €">

<div class="infogrey">  
<h2 class="producttitle">Urkundenmappe</h2>
<span class="price">4,95 €</span>
</div>

</a>

</div>





<div class="mix white">

<a href="/products/angebotsmappe">

<img src="{{ 'white.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Sammelmappe - DIN 4,95 €">

<div class="infowhite">    
<h2 class="producttitle">Sammelmappe</h2>
<span class="price">4,95 €</span>
</div>


</a>

</div>  





<div class="mix grey">

<a href="/products/angebotsmappe">

<img src="{{ 'grey.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Angebotsmappe - DIN 4,95 €">

<div class="infogrey">    
<h2 class="producttitle">Angebotsmappe</h2>
<span class="price">4,95 €</span>
</div>


</a>

</div>    





<div class="mix white">

<a href="/products/angebotsmappe">

<img src="{{ 'white.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Schnellhefter - DIN 4,95 €">

<div class="infowhite">      
<h2 class="producttitle">Schnellhefter</h2>
<span class="price">4,95 €</span>
</div>


</a>

</div>  





<div class="mix grey">

<a href="/products/angebotsmappe">

<img src="{{ 'grey.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Klemmmappe - DIN 4,95 €">

<div class="infogrey">        
<h2 class="producttitle">Klemmmappe</h2>
<span class="price">4,95 €</span>
</div>


</a>

</div>    





<div class="mix white">

<a href="/products/angebotsmappe">

<img src="{{ 'white.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Ringordner - DIN 4,95 €">

<div class="infowhite">          
<h2 class="producttitle">Ringordner</h2>
<span class="price">4,95 €</span>
</div>


</a>

</div>
```

[image]
Maybe a JavaScript solution?

Comment: This can be done with CSS only. Do you not already have it? Or are you worried about the background colors?

Comment: If you're looking for a simple plug-in solution, you could use Twitter Boot strap - getbootstrap.com. 

To do it yourself, using :nth-child() in media queries would work.

Comment: @Alexander H, can you give an html code of block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't need to support IE8 and earlier, you can use the CSS3 [`nth-child()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). the css design is for the illustration, change it to what you need:

```
.mix
{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.mix img
{
    display: inline-block;    
    max-width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:568px)
{
    .mix
    {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .mix:nth-child(4n+1), .mix:nth-child(4n+4)
    {  
        background: #999;
    }  
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px)
{
    .mix
    {
        width: 33.333%;
    }

    .mix:nth-child(4n+1), .mix:nth-child(4n+4)
    {  
        background: none;
    }

    .mix:nth-child(odd)
    {  
        background: #999;
    }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7h36fjnq/ - resize the window to see it working.

Comment: it's an option, but you can also leave it like this and change the Hex from #999 in the example to the one you use in the images, i've chosen the #999 color for better contrast on the example. your real color looks like #F1F1F1.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad, yea, use transparent png.

Comment: Can't this be done, witout transparent images? Give every div a individual number and reorder them with a js call that depends on the media breaks?

Comment: don't involve js if you don't have to. instead of background colors i've used float right to every third 'mix' class of group of four (only on min-width: 568px). like before, i've used the #999 for the contrast but change it to #F2F2F2 or remove it, the game now is not about the color, it's about placements. result: http://jsfiddle.net/7h36fjnq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some kind of responsive grid system. 
There are a lot of existing examples. Check out this one:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Grid systems:

http://getbootstrap.com

http://foundation.zurb.com

http://www.responsivegridsystem.com

Comment: He don't need to know how to resize. He just need to switch background color of div and every one next to it when it comes to 50% of width

Answer (score 0):

There are several good libraries for this sorry if thing. Twitter bootstrap is the most common/popular, but it has been around long enough for other, more radical solutions to become available. My personal favorite is semantic-ui. You can have divs that are only visible on different device types, making it possible to design an interface for mobile and an interface for the desktop at different sizes.

Twitter bootstrap is probably the best choice, but semantic is definitely worth looking at.